# What does Grade value not update for give test case?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Person {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected int idNumber;

    // Constructor
    Person(String firstName, String lastName, int identification){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.idNumber `enter code here`= identification;
    }

    // Print person data
    public void printPerson(){
         System.out.println(
                "Name: " + lastName + ", " + firstName 
            +   "\nID: " + idNumber); 
    }

}
class Student extends Person{
    private int[] testScores;
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int id, int scores[])
        {
        super(firstName,lastName,id);
        this.testScores = scores;
    }
    public char calculate()
        {
        int sum =0,avg;
        char grade = 'X';
        for(int i=0;i<testScores.length;i++)
            {
            sum = sum + testScores[i];
        }
       // System.out.println(sum);
        avg = sum/(testScores.length);
       // System.out.println(avg);
        if(avg<=100 && avg>=90)
            grade = 'O';
        else if(avg>90 && avg<=80)
            grade = 'E';
        else if(avg>80 && avg<=70)
            grade = 'A';
        else if(avg>70 && avg<=55)
            grade = 'P';
        else if(avg>55 && avg<=40)
            grade = 'D';
        else if(avg<40)
            grade = 'T';
        return grade;
    }

}
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName = scan.next();
        String lastName = scan.next();
        int id = scan.nextInt();
        int numScores = scan.nextInt();
        int[] testScores = new int[numScores];
        for(int i = 0; i < numScores; i++){
            testScores[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        scan.close();

        Student s = new Student(firstName, lastName, id, testScores);
        s.printPerson();
        System.out.println("Grade: " + s.calculate() );
    }
}
```

This code is run for following test case:

> Ritika Trikha 3648762 6 100 50 70 60 80 60

The expected result is:

```
Name: Trikha, Ritika
ID: 3648762
Grade: A
```

But this code does not update grade value for this case. I did not understand why. Please let me know if any of you finds the mistake.

Comment: Your `>` and `<=` are reversed, except in the first and last case. You want `if(avg < 90 && avg >= 80)`.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mathematical conditions were wrong, it should be

```
if(avg <= 100 && avg >= 90)
    grade = 'O';
else if(avg < 90 && avg >= 80)
    grade = 'E';
else if(avg < 80 && avg >= 70)
    grade = 'A';
else if(avg < 70 && avg >= 55)
    grade = 'P';
else if(avg < 55 && avg >= 40)
    grade = 'D';
else if(avg < 40)
```